# How can use image resize code data in PHP?

Tags: php

**I'm using this code in my php file but it does't work please help me**
Its Help Me alot
global $ulogo;
$paththumb = $ulogo;
$filename = $_FILES['fleimage']['name'];
$filename_tmp = $_FILES['fleimage']['tmp_name'];
function getExtension($str) {
$i = strrpos($str,".");
if (!$i) { return ""; }
$l = strlen($str) - $i;
$ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
return $ext;
}
if($filename != '')
{
$catfile = $filename;
$no = rand(1,999);
$tno = rand(1,999);
$image = $filename;
$uploadedfile = $filename;
$newfile = $no.$image;
$filename = stripslashes($filename);
$extension = getExtension($filename);
$extension = strtolower($extension);
if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png"))
{
header('Location: ../logo.php?m=3');
exit();
}
if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" )
{
$uploadedfile = $filename_tmp;
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
}
else if($extension=="png")
{
$uploadedfile = $filename_tmp;
$src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
}
else
{
$src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
}
list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);
$setheight=100;
$ratio=0.0;
if($height>$setheight)
{
$ratio=$setheight/$height;
$newheight = $height * $ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
$newwidth = $width * $ratio;
}
else
{
$newheight =70;
}
$tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight, $width,$height);
$tcatfile = $tno.$filename;
$filename = "$paththumb/". $tcatfile;
imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);
imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($tmp);

Comment: Consider editing your question to include a description of how the code does not work. Including error messages would also be helpful.

Comment: for uploading image in database and folder doesn't work